# InDesign CS5 Script: Oval 'transformReferencePoint'

Tags: javascript, object, methods, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to change the reference point of an oval in javascript for an InDesign CS5 script.
Here's what I've been trying:

```
function addFid(top, left, bottom, right) {
  var circle = myDoc.ovals.add();
  circle.geometricBounds = [top, left, bottom, right];
  circle.fillColor = myDoc.swatches.item("Black");
  circle.strokeWeight = 0;
  // Apparently, this Object does not support this property or method
  circle.transformReferencePoint = AnchorPoint.CENTER_ANCHOR;
}
```

For some reason though, when I run this, I get "Object does not support the property or method 'transformReferencePoint'"

I can't find the correct property or method anywhere though (at least not for ovals)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformReferencePoint is a LayoutWindow property.

```
app.activeWindow.transformReferencePoint = AnchorPoint.CENTER_ANCHOR;
```

That should solve your issue.

Loic

Comment: sorry, i'm not super savvy when it comes to indesign. So in inDesign, a window has reference points, not the elements?

Comment: Yep but depending on your intentions, you might not need to use it. If you resize object and wish that this transormation occurs from a certain "transformReferencePoint", you can use an AnchorPoint enumeration.